# React gives me twice the API result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my app in rect that consumes an api, works correctly but it doubles the result. That is, it gives me the correct result but 2 times in a row. Are my first steps in REACT

This is my REACT component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


function Clientes () {
    // Trabajar con el State
    // clientes = State
    // guardarClientes = Funcion para guardar el State
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});


    //Query a la API
    const consultarAPI = async() => {
        // console.log('Consultando...');
        const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');
        // console.log(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);

        // Colocar el resultado en el State
        guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);
    }

    //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
    useEffect( () => {
        consultarAPI();
    }, [] );


    function createArray(clientes) {
        if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
          return clientes.forEach(cliente => console.log(cliente)
          );
        }
        return [];
      }




    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {/* {console.log(clientes)} */}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}

            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Clientes;
```

The code works very well but in the terminal it gives me 2 times the same.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening. You don't need to put the full code in the demo, just create a simple one which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks for the warning I didn't know him

Comment: Tip: Don't mix languages when coding. Use the basic language of the programming language (so usually english) - even if it's not your mother language and code as if you're writing an english text. It's confusing if some parts are written in english and some parts in another language. When looking for a method/class/member it's not intuitive how it's probably called, when languages are mixed. Moreover it's more maintainable, easier to debug for others and it gets more readable, since you can kind of write an english text and really 'use' the english programming keywords.

Comment: I am new and did not know these things thanks for telling me

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the api call function inside the useEffect hook, like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


function Clientes () {
    // Trabajar con el State
    // clientes = State
    // guardarClientes = Funcion para guardar el State
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});


    //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
    useEffect( () => {

      //Query a la API
      const consultarAPI = async () => {

          const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');

          // Colocar el resultado en el State
          guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);
      }

      consultarAPI();
    }, [] );


    function createArray(clientes) {
      if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
        return clientes.forEach(cliente => console.log(cliente)
        );
      }
      return null; // <-- Change to return null if no clients are present. 
    }




    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            
            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Clientes;
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why is the necessary?

Comment: Hi Francisco, I have tried it but it keeps duplicating in both ways.
If I remove the console nothing comes out.
I dont know .....

Comment: Hi Paul, At this point of the project it does not affect me much but when I duplicate the result I thought that it would give me problems later.
So that's the question

Comment: It duplicate the `console.log` because the component is rendered twice, and because of that it's calling the function `createArray` two times. I don't know exactly why is rendering the component more than once, but this is the answer, I will continue researching on that.